# how to upload image of type png on server

Tags: ios

My question could be marked as duplicate but after going through tons of solutions I am still not able to figure out where am i going wrong. Please help.

Name of my image is 'image.png'.Please do specify what should be included in BoundaryConstant. I have just copied it from some site.

`//    // create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://....."];
[request setURL:requestURL];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";
NSString *filename = @"image";
// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are extra `\r\n` characters (see point 2 below), but it otherwise looks OK. Without seeing the server code, nor the `NSURLResponse` object, nor the `NSError` object, we can't diagnose what might be going wrong.

A few details:

1. I would not include dashes at the start of the boundary. If nothing else, it makes it really hard to differentiate the leading `--` from the actual boundary.
2. You are writing an extra `\r\n` before the boundaries. I'd replace

   ```
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```

   with

   ```
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```

   And replace

   ```
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```

   with

   ```
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```

   As it is (in particular, where you added the image data, a `\r\n`, and then `\r\n--%@--\r\n`), you're adding an extra two bytes (namely, `\r\n`) to the end of the uploaded image. This is generally doesn't cause problems (the image generally still works), but it is not correct.
3. You generally don't have to set the `Content-Length` header.
4. Do not use synchronous requests. Use `sendAsynchronousRequest`.
5. You are using `nil` for `response` and `error` objects. If you do that, you are extremely limited as to what diagnostics you can perform. You are flying blind. One should always examine the resulting `NSURLResponse` and `NSError` objects.
6. We cannot tell whether this upload would work without seeing the server code. In particular, I find your use of a variable named `filename` with a value of of `image` as the `name` of the field  as a little confusing. But if your `$_FILES` on the server (or if not using PHP, whatever field name its looking for) is looking for `image`, that's fine. It's just a confused/misleading choice of variable name. I'd probably call that variable `fieldName` or something like that.

   Most importantly, is `$_FILES` looking for a field name called `image`?
7. You have a line that says:

   ```
   [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
   ```

   That could just be:

   ```
   [body appendData:imageData];
   ```

   No need to create new `NSData`.
8. I'd remove that second call to `setURL`. That isn't necessary.
9. You are loading `image.png`, converting it to a `UIImage` and then using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to get `NSData`. That can work but is very inefficient. Just load the contents of the file into `NSData` directly, bypassing `UIImage` altogether.

   Also, I'd suggest you log an error message if the image is not found. Right now, it will simply skip the step of adding the image (meaning that it will silently send the request, not telling you if there was a problem).
10. You should watch this request in a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com). If you're going to get in this level of detail in preparing requests, you should inspect the requests as they go out.
11. I'd suggest you just use something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which gets you out of these sorts of weeds. If you want to do this yourself, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252378/1271826.

Comment: thanx bro!  In context to point no 6 plz tell me what is passed in a name? Name of my image is image.png so i have just used the word 'image'. Also let me know if BoundaryConstant could be just any constant. Why is it made so long?

Comment: When upload isn't files, there are two "names" that we concern ourselves with. The "field name" is the predetermined identifier that the server code is looking for when files are uploaded. Think of this as part of the web service API. So look at what field name the server is expecting. The "file name", on the other hand, is the name of the file being uploaded and this may change at runtime depending upon which files the user chooses to upload. What's confusing here is that your variable `filename` is actually being used as the field name. Lol.

Comment: Yes, the boundary string can be any string value, but you want to make sure it's a sequence of characters that will _never_ occur within the field values being sent. If the boundary string was merely "x", you'd have a 1 out of 256 chance that it would occur within any random value. If boundary string is "xx", that chance drops to 1 out of 65,536. If "xxxx", 1 out of 4 billion. Etc. So by making this string fairly long, it makes it astronomically unlikely that it will ever occur within a field value.

Comment: You should use a field name in your client code that matches the field name in your server code. So what field name does your server code use?

Comment: finally my code is working. It was fieldname that was causing all the trouble. Thanx Rob for helping me throughout.