# Difference between multipart form upload and NSURLSession.uploadTaskWithRequest

Tags: ios, multipartform-data, nsurlsession

Coming from the world of web programming, I'm pretty much comfortable with working with multipart form requests to upload files. However, in iOS, we have a thing called `NSURLSession` with the method `uploadTaskWithRequest`, which seems to be the method to call to do image uploads and the likes.

Can you explain the difference between the two approach, *multipart form upload* vs `uploadTaskWithRequest`? If I already have a backend that handle multipart form uploads, what kind of adjustments that I might need so that it support `uploadTaskWithRequest` as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `uploadTaskWithRequest` simply sends the `NSData`, file, or stream as the body of the request. It doesn't do anything beyond that. It simply has the benefit that it can be used with background sessions.

So, if you have web service that is expecting `multipart/form-data` request, you have to build that request yourself (unless you use something like AFNetworking or Alamofire to do this for you). Once you've built that request, you can either use `dataTaskWithRequest` (having set the `HTTPBody` of the `NSMutableURLRequest`) or `uploadTaskWithRequest` (in which case you don't set `HTTPBody`, but rather provide it as a parameter to `uploadTaskWithRequest`).

By the way, a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) is very useful in these cases, letting you observe what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Rob, I'm trying to create a `multipart/form-data` using `uploadTaskWithRequest`. How do I provide the body as a parameter?

Comment: You first have to build the multipart body (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26163136/1271826 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/24252378/1271826), and then supply it as the `data` parameter to `uploadTaskWithRequest`. Or, if you're trying to do this with background session (which doesn't allow `NSData` rendition), you'd save that multipart data as a file, and then supply that file as a parameter to `uploadTaskWithRequest`.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I've fixed the problem by using a `NSURLSessionDataTask` with the `dataTaskWithRequest` method. :)

Answer (score 2):

**File Upload with `multipart/form-data`**

The first approach using a `multipart/form-data` Content-type was originally defined in [RFC 1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867), then moved to the World Wide Web Consortium, which included it in the specification for [HTML 4.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/), where forms are expressed in HTML and where form values are sent via HTTP and electronic mail. When the form has been filled out by a user the form was sent to the server. This technique is widely supported and used by browsers and web servers.

However `multipart/form-data` can also be used to define form data which are presented in other representations than HTML. That is, you don't necessarily need a web browser or web server. The current specification which can be used by a wide variety of applications and transported by a wide variety of protocols is [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) (form IETF).

It must be mentioned, though, that the `multipart/form-data` content type was not always/is not without issues. It is quite complex by itself. Additionally, it uses/refers to a lot of other RFCs and - as a result of clearing things up - it and those which it depends on have been changed, obsoleted and updated quite frequently. Due to its complexity, serialisers and parsers are getting quite complicated, too and there's a lot of room for bugs and other issues.

**NSURLSession uploadTaskWithRequest**

How `NSURLSession` composes a request is not precisely documented. It certainly does not use a `multipart/form-data` content type, though.

For upload tasks, `NSURLSession` uses a POST request with a `NSURLRequest` as parameter which you can setup yourself. That is, you optionally can set the content type (for example `text/plain; charset=utf-8)`, and other headers. `NSURLSession` can also derive an appropriate content type itself from the given content (file, stream or NSData). That is, we may say, it becomes a "simple" POST request. Due to less complexity, the request is less troublesome.

So, in order for your server to support an `uploadTaskWithRequest` where a file should be uploaded, it should simply support a POST request with some "simple" content type. That is, as opposed to a "file upload" with a `multipart/form-data` content type which contains the file name in a disposition header, the server would need to return the URL of the location where the resource (the file) has been written to.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, it is quite easy to do a multipart/form-data POST request in the background, for example if you want to upload an image along with some other information.

First, create the NSMutableURLRequest in the same way like you would for a synchronous request (see for example [POST multipart/form-data with Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250475/post-multipart-form-data-with-objective-c/24252378#24252378)).

Then, write the body of the request to a file and supply it to the uploadTaskWithRequest method of the NSURLSession that you created with a backgroundSessionConfiguration:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                           NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] 
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageUUID];

[request.HTTPBody writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [urlSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request 
                                           fromFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
[task resume];
```

If you have multiple tasks and want to be able to distinguish them in the delegate callback, you can set a parameter (after you have created the request) with the NSURLProtocol class:

```
[NSURLProtocol setProperty:imageUUID
                    forKey:@"yourKeyForTheImageUUID" 
                 inRequest:request];
```

and get it back in the callback like this:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
        task:(nonnull NSURLSessionTask *)task
        didCompleteWithError:(nullable NSError *)error
{
    NSString *imageUUID = [NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:@"yourKeyForTheImageUUID"
                                              inRequest:task.originalRequest];
```