# Swift Image upload via HTTP $_POST

Tags: php, swift, http, post

I'm using this code (Swift) to upload an image that user selected from their photos to a server:

```
let imageFormatted = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 0.5);
    let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
    print ("MARK -- UUID is " + uuid)
    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        "http://www.memer.onlie/upload.php",
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageFormatted!, name: "imagefile",
                fileName: uuid + ".jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.validate()
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.displayAlert("Uploaded!", message: "Your meme was uploaded, and you might see it in the app soon!", responseButtonText: "<3")
                    }
                    var json = JSON(data: response.data!)
                    print ("MARK -- JSON response: " + json["response"].stringValue)
                }
                print ("MARK -- Upload success!")
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                print ("MARK -- Upload failure!")
                self.displayAlert("Issue uploading.", message: "There was an issue uploading your meme.", responseButtonText: "Aww :(")
            }
        }
    )
```

No image is being uploaded to the server. What can I correct to get this to work?

Edited code.

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118081/difference-between-multipart-form-upload-and-nsurlsession-uploadtaskwithrequest) helps you understand what you have not considered and what you need to do to solve the issue. I guess you need to set request header and body part properly. If you use Alamofire and have to use 'multipart/form-data' encoding type, you can write code like this.

```
    Alamofire.upload(.POST, destURL, headers: yourHeader, multipartFormData: {    multipartFormData in

        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name:"file", fileName: "imagefile", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }

        // Append parameters you should send  
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        }

        }, encodingCompletion: {  encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult {

            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.validate()
                upload.responseJSON { response in

                // do something if response is success
                }

            case .Failure(_):
                // do something if response is fail
            }
    })
```

Comment: I'm using this, see the edited post for the code, but it's not sending to the server and there isn't a response. @woogii

Comment: Don't you have any HTTP header or extra parameters? What's the error you get from the response?  You can refer to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire/26747857#26747857) where it shows various example codes about Alamorfire Upload request.