# iOS; Post image from UIImageView to PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift, image, post

I'm developing an iOS app with Xcode and Swift.

I usually take this code to POST data to PHP:

```
let requestImage = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com/postData.php")!)
requestData.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postStringImage = "name=\(name.text!)&age=\(age.text!)"
requestData.HTTPBody = postStringImage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Now I want to post an image that's in a UIImageView to PHP:
Can I simple do something like this?
Code:

```
let requestImage = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com/postImage.php")!)
requestData.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postStringImage = "image=\(MyImage)"
requestData.HTTPBody = postStringImage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

What do I have to do to make it working?

BTW:

I took this code to test my PHP script via browser:

```
<form action="postImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a PHP script that accepts multipart/form-data. Because this you need your POST request to be a multipart/form-data.
Try this example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252378/2441775

If you have any question, feel free to request again. I'll try to answer.

Comment: David, there are lot's of samples in stack overflow to your problem. In the same answer that comment, I found another, this time in swift. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26163136/2441775
I don't develop in swift, because that I can't help too much, but the main idea is in booth samples.

Comment: I'm not able to get it working. Maybe because I'm doing something wrong when trying to convert the Objective-c code to Swift code (because I use Swift in my project). Do you know a better solution? Or is there a library for it?

Comment: David, post your code to me. I can try analyze to find the problem.

Comment: Hey, @Mário Klein, thanks for trying to help me. Do you mean the Objective-c code I tried to convert in Swift code?

Comment: Hi David, no problem. I mean the code in swift that doesn't works for you. I can try to identify the problem.