# Unable to open OneNote webUrl in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, onedrive, onenote

I am using OneNote API for creating note in OneNote from my ios application. After creating note api returns two url clientUrl and webUrl.

```
clientUrl => Link open page in the installed client 
webUrl => Link to open page in OneNote Online
```

Now the problem is webUrl is successfully opening in iPad but not in iPhone. In iPhone i am getting **safari can not open the page**.

This is the code i did for opening webUrl.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webUrl];
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

Also i tried to open clientUrl but what if user have no OneNote app installed in device ?

Please help me on this why i am unable to open URL ? Is there any specific reason behind this ?

Comment: May o know which iOS version on your iPhone ?

Comment: @CodeChanger 10.2.1

Comment: Have you tried opening the clientUrl?

Comment: Yes same for clientUrl also. If OneNote app is installed in device then it working. Url redirect to me in OneNote app. But what about if OneNote app is not installed in device ?

Comment: @JorgeAguirre any update ?

Comment: @JorgeAguirre please let me know what is actual problem is there from my side or in URL ?

Comment: Can you share screenshots of what you see when you open the web url? Do you simply see "Safari cannot open the page"?

Comment: An example of the web url would be useful as well.

Comment: Yes i am getting Safari could not open the page.

Comment: @JorgeAguirre which example of web url ?

Comment: The one that you are trying to open.

Comment: But in this it is not opening so any suggestion ? Don't know now what to do for this.