# How to upload an image from a dictionary that contains other text parametes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to upload an image from a dictionary which looks like this,
{
  pic_image :           file attache
  pic_user_id   :           1 
  pic_name  :           abcd.jpg
}

where file attached is the image i want to upload from the image view, How to achieve this?

this my function to upload image that is inside a dictionary

```
-(void)uploadImageWithparams:(NSDictionary *)params withDelegate:(id)delegateObject withHandler:(HMResponseBlock)block{
    // This isn't actually my url btw
    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",kBaseUrl,@"page=user"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    NSMutableArray *parameters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in params.allKeys) {
        if([key rangeOfString:@"pic_image"].location != NSNotFound){
            [parameters addObject:@{@"fileName": key, @"value": params[key]}];
        }else {
            [parameters addObject:@{@"name": key, @"value": params[key]}];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"The parameters are %@",parameters);
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
      NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
     NSError *error;
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    for (NSDictionary *param in parameters) {
        if (param[@"fileName"]) {

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"abcd"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:param[@"value"]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        }else {
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param[@"name"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", param[@"value"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        }
    }
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary]   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                    } else {
                                                        NSDictionary *json =  nil;
                                                        NSError *err;
                                                        if(data){
                                                            json =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
                                                        }
                                                        block(json,err);
                                                    }
                                                }];
    [dataTask resume];

}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are really want to do because no language, no develop environment mentioned. It looks like some JSON protocol, so the pic_image can be converted to ASCII characters by Base64 encoding on the network. Second, considering the image view you mentioned, what language and framework do you use?

Comment: its multipart sending data see this ans, can be use for you ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250475/post-multipart-form-data-with-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

Get image name from dictionary by key name

ex:

```
NSString *imageName = myDictioanry[@"pic_name"];
```

by this code you can get image name from dictionary

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

you can get image from image name by above code

or else you can get image from imageView and convert to NSData by below code

```
    UIImage *image = myImageView.image;
```

if you want code for upload image to server, click this link

[imageUploadLink](http://tommaso.pavese.me/2013/09/09/uploading-images-with-objective-c/)

Comment: Thank you i will try the one in the link